# I have a question about integrating, and what to do about the constant. $\int\frac{1}{1-z}dz$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, power-series

http://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/pdf/upload_library/2/Kalman-2013.pdf

On page 44, they conclude that $g'(z) = - \displaystyle\frac{\ln(1-z)}{z}$ by saying that it is just $\displaystyle\frac{f(z)}{z}$. So whats happening is that we would get,

$f(z) = \displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k}z^k$. Then $f'(z) = \displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}z^{k-1} = 1 + z + z^2 + ... = \frac{1}{1-z}$ for $|z| < 1$.

Then if we take $\displaystyle\int\frac{1}{1-z}dz$ we get $f(z) = \displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k}z^k = -\ln(1-z)$. From here you just divide both sides by $z$ and one gets the result.

Here is my question. If you integrate, one is going to get a constant $C$ with it. Now the paper says to just take $f(0)$ which makes $C = 0$. Of course it will make it zero but I don't understand why you can just randomly do that. I always thought the constant would not be there only if one computed a definite integral. Can this be thought of as a definite integral? The constant is just confusing me because the way I set it up, obviously an indefinite integral will have a $+ C$.

The help would be appreciated!

Comment: The text actually says "we know from the definition that $f(0)=0$", there's nothing random in choosing the constant $C$ that ensures that.

Comment: When they say they know from the definition, what definition do they mean? And so you can't set this up as a definite integral?

Comment: Did you read the article ? The definition is (1). Using a definite integral or setting the constant are equivalent. If the primitive is $F(x)+C$, solving $F(x_0)+C=F_0$ gives $C=F_0-F(x_0)$ and the primitive is $F(x)-F(x_0)+F_0$.

Comment: I guess what I am saying is that if $f(0) = 0$, then yes $C = 0$. But couldn't one choose any other number and we would not get $C = 0$?

Comment: Using a definite integral or setting the constant are equivalent.

Comment: Okay then I think I will get it if you just do an example. Maybe show a definite integral with my problem and then set the constant as well. Im sorry. I apologize for not understanding it as much as I should. Examples always help clear things up at least for me.

Comment: If you know the initial value of the function, then the value of the constant can be determined. In this case, the value of the function at $x=0$ is zero. Because we know that sum of zeros is zero.

Answer (score 3):

Equation (1) in the article says
$$
f(z) = \sum \frac{1}{k} z^k =  z + \frac{z^2}{2} + \frac{z^3}{3} + \frac{z^4}{4} + \ldots
$$
This serves as the definition of the function $f(z)$.  Notice that $f$ is not used anywhere in the article until it is introduced in equation (1).

Now, a bit of calculus shows $f(z) = -\ln(1 - z) + C$, and you were OK with that--your question is about how to find $C$.

By plugging in $z=0$ into equation (1), we get:
$$
f(0) = 0 + \frac{0^2}{2} + \frac{0^3}{3} + \frac{0^4}{4} + \ldots
$$
This series sums to $0$, so we have $f(0) = 0$. Thus
$$
0 = f(0) = -\ln(1 - 0) + C = 0 + C = C,
$$
so $C = 0$.  Therefore $f(z) = -\ln(1-z)$. $\Box$